# How to merge/join consecutive lines

Tags: python, regex

How do I merge every single batch of consecutive lines in a .txt file?

**Example:**

Turn this:

```
User#0001
Hello
Whats Up


User#0002
Hi
...
```

into this:

```
User#0001 Hello Whats Up


User#0002 Hi
...
```

I want to merge all of the lines because when I've tried doing this:

```py
pattern = r'([a-zA-Z]+#[0-9]+.)(.+?(?:^$|\Z))'
```

```py
data = {
    'name': [],
    'message': []
}
```

```py
with open('chat.txt', 'rt') as file:
  for message in file.readlines():
    match = re.findall(pattern, message, flags=re.M|re.S)
    print(match)
    if match:
      name, message = match[0]
      data['name'].append(name)
      data['message'].append(message)
```

I got this when printing 'match':

```
[('User#0001', '\n')]
[]
[]
[]
[('User#0002', '\n')
...
```

And when manually editing some of the lines to be `User#0001 message` then it does return the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your requirement using `re.sub`:

```py
inp = """User#0001
Hello
Whats Up


User#0002
Hi"""

output = re.sub(r'(?<!\n)\n(?=\S)', ' ', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
User#0001 Hello Whats Up


User#0002 Hi
```

The regex used here says to match:

- `(?<!\n)` assert that newline does not precede
- `\n` match a single newline
- `(?=\S)` assert that non whitespace follows

The `(?<!\n)` ensures that we do not remove the newline on the line before a text block begins.  The `(?=\S)` ensures that we do not remove the final newline in a text block.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7YQ3C/1)):

```py
import re

s = """\
User#0001
Hello
Whats Up


User#0002
Hi"""

pat = re.compile(r"^(\S+#\d+)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^\S+#\d+|\Z)", flags=re.M | re.S)
out = [(user, messages.splitlines()) for user, messages in pat.findall(s)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[("User#0001", ["Hello", "Whats Up"]), ("User#0002", ["Hi"])]
```

---

If you want to join the messages to one line:

```
for user, messages in out:
    print(user, " ".join(messages))
```

Prints:

```
User#0001 Hello Whats Up
User#0002 Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I suspect that your need is for historical recording.
Then I would say that you do not need a dictionary.
I propose a list where each element would be (user,message).
Second, complexity bring difficulties and bugs. Do you really need regex?
What's wrong with this simple solution:

```
t= [
"User#0001\n",
"Hello\n",
"Whats Up\n",
"\n",
"\n",
"User#0002\n",
"Hi\n",
"...\n",
]

data=[]

for line in t:
  line = line.strip() # remove spaces and \n
  if line.strip().startswith( "User#"):
    data.append( [line,""])
  else:
    data[-1][1] += ' ' + line
for msg in data:
  print( msg[0], msg[1] if len(msg)>1 else "")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the format of the given example, if you want to keep the same amount of newlines, you can use a pattern with 3 capture groups.

```
^([a-zA-Z]+#[0-9]+)((?:\n(?![a-zA-Z]+#[0-9]).+)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([a-zA-Z]+#[0-9]+)` Capture **group 1**
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group
  - `\n` Match a newline
  - `(?![a-zA-Z]+#[0-9])` Negative lookahead, assert not 1+ chars a-zA-Z to the right followed by `#` and a digit
  - `.+` Match 1+ chars (In your pattern you used `^$` to stop when there is an empty string, but you can also make sure to match 1 or more characters)
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to also allow 0 occurrences
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF9sdN/1)

```
import re

s = """User#0001
Hello
Whats Up


User#0002
Hi

User#0003"""
pattern = r"^([a-zA-Z]+#[0-9]+)((?:\n(?![a-zA-Z]+#[0-9]).+)*)(\n*)"
result = []
for (u, m, n) in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M):
    result.append(f"{' '.join([u] + m.split())}{n}")

print("".join(result))
```

Output

```
User#0001 Hello Whats Up


User#0002 Hi

User#0003
```